# Access token retrieved with MSAL does not contain group IDs

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-ad-msal, msal-react, msal

I want to include group IDs in the access token retrieved with MSAL in my React web client. I retrieve the access token with:

```js
const accessToken = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
    scopes: [
      "https://graph.windows.net/Group.Read.All",
      "https://graph.windows.net/User.Read",
    ],
    account: accounts[0],
  })
).accessToken;
```

I have granted the app registration the `Microsoft Graph API Group.Read.All (delegated)` permission in Azure. I have also added `groups` as an optional claim in the `Token configuration section`. So the app manifest now has the following properties:

```json
{
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    (...)
    "groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup",
    (...)
    "optionalClaims": {
        "accessToken": [
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            }
        ],
    },
    (...)
}
```

I successfully retrieve a access token with a valid signature. The access token also include the following claim:

```json
{
   "scp": "Group.Read.All User.Read"
}
```

, but it is missing the expected `groups` claim which should include a list of group IDs. What have I configured incorrectly?

It seems like the `id_token` retrieved with MSAL contains the group IDs, but not the access token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** that: Using the manifest of the resource, access tokens are generated not by using the client. To get the optional claims in the access token request the token for your application. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/optional-claims#configure-directory-extension-optional-claims).

- As you are generating access token for  `https://graph.windows.net/` that is the resource is Microsoft Graph hence the access token is generated for the client not your application.
- Modifying the Manifest and requesting access token for other resources doesn't fetch claims in access token.

**Hence to get the Group IDs in the access token, `Expose an API` like below:**

[image]

Grant the API permissions:

[image]

Now I generated access token by passing **scope** as **`api://ClientID/test.read`**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:api://xxx/test.read 
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
code:code
```

[image]

***When I decoded the access token, Group IDs are displayed:***

[image]

**Modify your code like below:**

```js
const accessToken = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
    scopes: [
      "api://ClientID/ScopeName",
          ],
    account: accounts[0],
  })
).accessToken;
```

Comment: Thank you! Just a small note; my app registration already had a App ID URI defined as `https://myapp.mycompany.com` . By adding a new scope called `user_read`, and afterwards adding it to the API Permissions, then modifying the code to using `scopes: ["https://myapp.mycompany.com/user_read"]`, I do get the expected access token.

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot of Expose an API page?

Answer (score 1):

When you define the optional claim, you are saying "include the group IDs in access tokens for this API".
You are getting an access token for Microsoft Graph API, not your API.
And they are not configuring group IDs to be included.

You need to define a scope in the Expose an API tab of your app registration, and use that when acquiring an access token.
That token will then contain the group IDs.